# How to implement dynamic VLOOKUP in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA function which will insert a dynamic vlookup command to the entire column (column "E"). My goal is to copy data from another sheet (called "WBTS"). Unfortunately, the syntax seems to be illegal. 'LastRow' represents the ultimate occupied row in that column.

```
For X = 2 To LastRow2
Cells(X, 5).Value = "=VLOOKUP(D"&X",WBTS!$D$2:$I$466,6,FALSE)"
Next X
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Cells(X, 5).formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & X & ",WBTS!$D$2:$I$466,6,FALSE)"
```

Comment: I still have one doubt and want to improve this command by replacing row identifier "466" with a variable "LastRow" which stores the ID of the last occupied row within this sheet. Unfortunately, I have difficulty with syntax and cannot implement it. Could anyone help me please?